# How to loop through dates using Bash?

Tags: bash, loops, date

I have such bash script:

```
array=( '2015-01-01', '2015-01-02' )

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    python /home/user/executeJobs.py {i} &> /home/user/${i}.log
done
```

Now I want to loop through a range of dates, e.g. 2015-01-01 until 2015-01-31.

How to achieve in Bash?

**Update**:

Nice-to-have: No job should be started before a previous run has completed. In this case, when executeJobs.py is completed bash prompt `$` will return.

e.g. could I incorporate `wait%1` in my loop?

Comment: Are you on a platform with GNU date?

Comment: check this link: http://www.glatter-gotz.com/blog/2011/02/19/looping-through-dates-in-a-bash-script-on-osx/

Comment: BTW, since you have a Python interpreter handy, this would be much, much easier to do in a reliable and portable way using the `datetime` Python module.

Comment: Works as specified: `array=(2015-01-{01..31})` \*lol\*

Comment: @Cyrus, sure, but the reasonable assumption is that that was a bad choice of example data.

Comment: I dont understand why 2015-01-01 is a bad choice of sample data.

Comment: 2015-01-01 until 2015-01-31 does not span dates in more than one month, so it's a very simple case.

Comment: Editing a question to add unrelated restrictions after it already has complete and correct answers to add more restrictions is bad form. Ask a new question.

Comment: ...actually, the short form: `wait` only has any effect if your original process is in the background. The code given here doesn't put anything in the background. Thus, the answers given *already* wait for the command run to return before proceeding, thus, there's no need for any kind of explicit `wait`.

Comment: Yes I know, sorry. Below answers are still valid. Wouldn't too hard to incorporate the new problem.

Comment: ...if the Python script you're running does a self-detach (the only way it would background without `&` being used), then the shell doesn't know about that, so `wait` wouldn't be much good even so.

Comment: ...so, if you're actually seeing a _need_ to `wait` (as in, bugs happening due to concurrent processes when you don't), then you have something more interesting / more complicated going on, which needs a more complicated solution (like asking the subprocess to inherit a lockfile), which is enough complexity and sufficiently unrelated to date arithmetic that it should be a separate question.

Comment: The python script calls other bash scripts... to be precise mrjob and file system operations and pymongo.

Comment: I'm not sure why "calling other bash scripts" would change the accuracy of anything I've said above. `wait` will do absolutely nothing if no jobs have been started in the background **by the current shell** -- background jobs started by a subprocess do nothing -- using `&`.

Comment: So `wait$!` is bettter suited? I want to wait for ALL to finish before the loop continues, I though `wait%1` does just that.

Comment: `%1` only works at all in interactive prompts; it has no meaning in scripts. (Though, for that matter, `$!` only has meaning if you use `&` to background a task; if you don't use `&`, then there's no value set to `$!`, and also no reason whatsoever to use `wait`, since the default behavior without `&` is **always** to wait for the child to exit).

Comment: ...and, no, `wait %1` doesn't wait for all jobs to finish; it only waits for the first job in the table to finish. Though that's a meaningless concept in a noninteractive shell, which has no job table.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Using GNU date:

```
d=2015-01-01
while [ "$d" != 2015-02-20 ]; do 
  echo $d
  d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")

  # mac option for d decl (the +1d is equivalent to + 1 day)
  # d=$(date -j -v +1d -f "%Y-%m-%d" $d +%Y-%m-%d)
done
```

Note that because this uses string comparison, it requires full ISO 8601 notation of the edge dates (do not remove leading zeros). To check for valid input data and coerce it to a valid form if possible, you can use `date` as well:

```
# slightly malformed input data
input_start=2015-1-1
input_end=2015-2-23

# After this, startdate and enddate will be valid ISO 8601 dates,
# or the script will have aborted when it encountered unparseable data
# such as input_end=abcd
startdate=$(date -I -d "$input_start") || exit -1
enddate=$(date -I -d "$input_end")     || exit -1

d="$startdate"
while [ "$d" != "$enddate" ]; do 
  echo $d
  d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
done
```

**One final addition**: To check that `$startdate` is before `$enddate`, if you only expect dates between the years 1000 and 9999, you can simply use string comparison like this:

```
while [[ "$d" < "$enddate" ]]; do
```

To be on the very safe side beyond the year 10000, when lexicographical comparison breaks down, use

```
while [ "$(date -d "$d" +%Y%m%d)" -lt "$(date -d "$enddate" +%Y%m%d)" ]; do
```

The expression `$(date -d "$d" +%Y%m%d)` converts `$d` to a numerical form, i.e., `2015-02-23` becomes `20150223`, and the idea is that dates in this form can be compared numerically.

Comment: BTW, you could avoid the bug with endless looping when the date format isn't exact by preprocessing the end date in the code to match the `date` command's output format. (Bailing out when that command doesn't succeed is, similarly, better than an endless loop on bad input).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Most simply with `$(date -I -d "$enddate")`, yes. That would be a good idea if the dates come from user input/untrusted sources (as would checking `$?` afterwards).

Comment: I tend to prefer to just throw in `|| return` (assuming this is in a function) or `|| die "error message here"`, assuming such a function is defined, rather than testing `$?` explicitly, but yes.

Comment: Nice one, why not enhance with bug check like recommended.

Comment: Could we incorporate `wait%1` in that loop?

Comment: Sure, why not. It's just a shell loop, that it uses dates as iterator doesn't change what you can do inside it.

Comment: @SirBenBenji, ...that said, `%1` is a job control construct, and job control is turned off in noninteractive scripts unless you explicitly turn it on yourself. The proper way to refer to individual subprocesses inside a script is by PID, and even then, waiting for processes to complete is *automatic* unless they're explicitly backgrounded by your code (as with a `&`), or they self-detach (in which case `wait` won't even work, _and_ the PID given to the shell will be invalidated by the double-fork process used to self-background).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You'd have to remember `$!` in a script and `wait` on that, but that shouldn't really be a problem -- if you could make it work in an interactive shell with `wait %1`, you can make it work in a script as well. This could make sense if you wanted to do other work while the big job is running.

Comment: To be sure, but `$!` is only set if `&` is in use, and the OP has given no indication that it is; indeed, I've interpreted some statements made in follow-up conversation to the contrary.

Comment: As pointed out in [this near-duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221430/bash-looping-though-time/41221687#41221687) a Bash `for` loop would seem like a more natural solution.

Comment: @triplee a for loop is of course possible, but I would warn against converting dates to unix timestamps for this kind of calculation (as is done in the solution to the other question) because date and time handling is rife with corner cases and therefore prone to subtle bugs. In particular, all days do not have the same length because of leap seconds, so adding 86400 seconds to a timestamp is not the same as adding a day in all cases. What's worse, this is exactly the kind of corner case that's likely to be forgotten in testing.

Comment: After taking a closer look, it appears that leap seconds are excluded from the UNIX timestamp, so that some timestamps refer to a space of two seconds. This apparently makes ´gettimeofday` very interesting to implement in the sub-second range, and I suppose we should count ourselves lucky that leap seconds have never been *removed* from a year. This means I have to correct myself: Adding 86400 seconds to a unix timestamp is arguably always the same as adding a day, since there is no way to refer to 2016-12-31T23:59:60 specifically. TIL.

Comment: Running your first code (sh test.sh) gives me an error: date: illegal option -- I
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

Comment: For macOS it won't work, first install gnu date https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231224/how-to-have-gnus-date-in-os-x

Comment: MacOS user here. I installed gnu date as described in the link but I still receive the same error message as dorien.

Comment: OK, I got it to work. Installing gdate does not replace date. So replace ```date``` with ```gdate``` in the code above.

Comment: macOS does not need to install anything!!  see the comment about delcaring variable `d` if in mac.  you just need this instead: `d=$(date -j -v +1d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2020-12-12" +%Y-%m-%d)`

Comment: on Mac use
`d=$(date -j -v +1d -f "%Y-%m-%d" $d +%Y-%m-%d)`
instead of 
`d=$(date -j -v +1d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2020-12-12" +%Y-%m-%d)`

Answer (score 33):

[Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
for i in 2015-01-{01..31} …
```

More:

```
for i in 2015-02-{01..28} 2015-{04,06,09,11}-{01..30} 2015-{01,03,05,07,08,10,12}-{01..31} …
```

Proof:

```
$ echo 2015-02-{01..28} 2015-{04,06,09,11}-{01..30} 2015-{01,03,05,07,08,10,12}-{01..31} | wc -w
 365
```

Compact/nested:

```
$ echo 2015-{02-{01..28},{04,06,09,11}-{01..30},{01,03,05,07,08,10,12}-{01..31}} | wc -w
 365
```

Ordered, if it matters:

```
$ x=( $(printf '%s\n' 2015-{02-{01..28},{04,06,09,11}-{01..30},{01,03,05,07,08,10,12}-{01..31}} | sort -n -t"-" -k1 -k2 -k3) )
$ echo "${#x[@]}"
365
```

Since it's unordered, you can just tack leap years on:

```
$ echo {2015..2030}-{02-{01..28},{04,06,09,11}-{01..30},{01,03,05,07,08,10,12}-{01..31}} {2016..2028..4}-02-29 | wc -w
5844
```

Comment: What about leap years?

Comment: Can I then use `python /home/user/executeJobs.py 2015-01-{01..31} &> /home/user/2015-01-{01..31}.log`  ?

Comment: @SirBenBenji That depends on `executeJobs.py`.

Comment: I must say executeJobs needs the date parameter and I need to wait on each run to complete. It is a Big Data job and should under no circumstances started before each previous run has completed. I should have thought of this before, sorry for forgetting about it.

Comment: Oh Wow. Such power in simplicity.

Comment: The sort is lexographic so BEWARE!! This will not sort correctly. You can do a numeric sort and specify they keys and it will work: `sort -n -t"-" -k1 -k2 -k3`. I suggested an edit. the -t specified the separator in the dates.

Comment: @NoahGary I suppose you want to support years with other than the same number of digits. But if we're dealing with dates earlier than the year 1000, don't we have a whole bunch of other problems to solve?

Comment: @kojiro definitely and edge case... As well as leap years... Leap years would be easy to fix... But I think this answer shows how to simply generate a list with bracket expansion... It can be useful for generating any kind of calendar if you understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 22):

```
start='2019-01-01'
end='2019-02-01'

start=$(date -d $start +%Y%m%d)
end=$(date -d $end +%Y%m%d)

while [[ $start -le $end ]]
do
        echo $(date -d $start +%Y-%m-%d)
        start=$(date -d"$start + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d")

done
```

Comment: Careful, this one plays with the fact, that bash doesn't check variable types. It only works with the date format YMD - because that concatenates the date into something that looks like an integer, which make's two dates comparable. While 20200201 would be considered less than 20200202, it would not work with 2020-02-01 and 2020-02-02. OP asked for a dash-separated date.

Comment: @n.r. Good cautionary advise. Now it works also with dashed-separated date.

Answer (score 7):

The previous solution by @Gilli is pretty clever, because it plays with the fact, that you can simple format two dates make them look like integers. Then you can use -le / less-equal - which usually works with numeric data only.

Problem is, that this binds you to the date format YMD, like 20210201. If you need something different, like 2021-02-01 (that's what OP implicated as a requirement), the script will not work:

```
start='2021-02-01'
end='2021-02-05'

start=$(date -d $start +%Y-%m-%d)
end=$(date -d $end +%-Y%m-%d)

while [[ $start -le $end ]]
do
        echo $start
        start=$(date -d"$start + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d")

done
```

The output will look like this:

```
2021-02-01
2021-02-02
2021-02-03
2021-02-04
2021-02-05
2021-02-06
2021-02-07
./loop.sh: line 16: [[: 2021-02-08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

To fix that and use this loop for custom date formats, you need to work with one additional variable, let's call it "**d_start**":

```
d_start='2021-02-01'
end='2021-02-05'

start=$(date -d $d_start +%Y%m%d)
end=$(date -d $end +%Y%m%d)

while [[ $start -le $end ]]
do
        echo $d_start
        start=$(date -d"$start + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d")
        d_start=$(date -d"$d_start + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d")

done
```

This will lead to this output:

```
2021-02-01
2021-02-02
2021-02-03
2021-02-04
2021-02-05
```

Answer (score 6):

I needed to loop through dates on AIX, BSDs, Linux, OS X and Solaris. The `date` command is one of the least portable and most miserable commands to use across platforms I have encountered. I found it easier to write a `my_date` command that just worked everywhere.

The C program below takes a starting date, and adds or subtracts days from it. If no date is supplied, it adds or subtracts days from the current date.

The `my_date` command allows you to perform the following everywhere:

```sh
start="2015-01-01"
stop="2015-01-31"

echo "Iterating dates from ${start} to ${stop}."

while [[ "${start}" != "${stop}" ]]
do
    python /home/user/executeJobs.py {i} &> "/home/user/${start}.log"
    start=$(my_date -s "${start}" -n +1)
done
```

And the C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

int show_help();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int eol = 0, help = 0, n_days = 0;
    int ret = EXIT_FAILURE;

    time_t startDate = time(NULL);
    const time_t ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;

    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-l") == 0)
        {
            eol = 1;
        }
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-n") == 0)
        {
            if (++i == argc)
            {
                show_help();
                ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
                goto finish;
            }

            n_days = strtoll(argv[i], NULL, 0);
        }
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0)
        {
            if (++i == argc)
            {
                show_help();
                ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
                goto finish;
            }

            struct tm dateTime;
            memset (&dateTime, 0x00, sizeof(dateTime));

            const char* start = argv[i];
            const char* end = strptime (start, "%Y-%m-%d", &dateTime);

            /* Ensure all characters are consumed */
            if (end - start != 10)
            {
                show_help();
                ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
                goto finish;
            }

            startDate = mktime (&dateTime);
        }
    }

    if (help == 1)
    {
        show_help();
        ret = EXIT_SUCCESS;
        goto finish;
    }

    char buff[32];
    const time_t next = startDate + ONE_DAY * n_days;
    strftime(buff, sizeof(buff), "%Y-%m-%d", localtime(&next));

    /* Paydirt */
    if (eol)
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", buff);
    else
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", buff);

    ret = EXIT_SUCCESS;

finish:

    return ret;
}

int show_help()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage:\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "  my_date [-s date] [-n [+|-]days] [-l]\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "    -s date: optional, starting date in YYYY-MM-DD format\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "    -n days: optional, number of days to add or subtract\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "    -l: optional, add new-line to output\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "  If no options are supplied, then today is printed.\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're stuck with **busybox** date that is used in many distributions like alpine that are commonly used in docker containers, I've found working with timestamps to be the most reliable approach:

```
STARTDATE="2019-12-30"
ENDDATE="2020-01-04"

start=$(date -d $STARTDATE +%s)
end=$(date -d $ENDDATE +%s)

d="$start"
while [[ $d -le $end ]]
do
    date -d @$d +%Y-%m-%d

    d=$(( $d + 86400 ))
done
```

This will output:

```
2019-12-30
2019-12-31
2020-01-01
2020-01-02
2020-01-03
2020-01-04
```

Unix timestamps don't include leap seconds, so 1 day equals always exactly 86400 seconds.

Comment: This is the only one works inside some container ...

Comment: @user218867 right this is because most lightweight container OSes like Alpine only have the date packed into busybox but no GNU date to save space.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and I tried some of the above answers, maybe they are ok, but none of those answers fixed on what I was trying to do, using macOS.

I was trying to iterate over dates in the past, and the following is what worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the machine date
newDate=$(date '+%m-%d-%y')

# Set a counter variable
counter=1 

# Increase the counter to get back in time
while [ "$newDate" != 06-01-18 ]; do
  echo $newDate
  newDate=$(date -v -${counter}d '+%m-%d-%y')
  counter=$((counter + 1))
done
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I recommend not using a variable name that happens to coincide with a very powerful bit-for-bit copy command, but that's just me.

Comment: Simpler way is to use `gdate` instead of `date` in macOS.

Answer (score 5):

Bash is best written by leveraging pipes(|). This should result in memory efficient and concurrent(faster) processing. I would write the following:

```
seq 0 100 | xargs printf "20 Aug 2020 - %sdays\n" \
  | xargs -d '\n' -l date -d
```

The following will print the date of `20 aug 2020` and print the dates of the 100 days before it.

This oneliner can be made into a utility.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# date-range template <template>

template="${1:--%sdays}"

export LANG;

xargs printf "$template\n" | xargs -d '\n' -l date -d
```

By default we choose to iterate into the past 1 day at a time.

```
$ seq 10 | date-range
Mon Mar  2 17:42:43 CET 2020
Sun Mar  1 17:42:43 CET 2020
Sat Feb 29 17:42:43 CET 2020
Fri Feb 28 17:42:43 CET 2020
Thu Feb 27 17:42:43 CET 2020
Wed Feb 26 17:42:43 CET 2020
Tue Feb 25 17:42:43 CET 2020
Mon Feb 24 17:42:43 CET 2020
Sun Feb 23 17:42:43 CET 2020
Sat Feb 22 17:42:43 CET 2020
```

Let's say we want to generate dates up to a certain date. We don't know yet how many iterations we need to get there. Let's say Tom was born 1 Jan 2001. We want to generate each date till a certain one. We can achieve this by using sed.

```
seq 0 $((2**63-1)) | date-range | sed '/.. Jan 2001 /q'
```

> The `$((2**63-1))` trick is used to create a big integer.

Once sed exits it will also exit the date-range utility.

One can also iterate using a 3 month interval:

```
$ seq 0 3 12 | date-range '+%smonths'
Tue Mar  3 18:17:17 CET 2020
Wed Jun  3 19:17:17 CEST 2020
Thu Sep  3 19:17:17 CEST 2020
Thu Dec  3 18:17:17 CET 2020
Wed Mar  3 18:17:17 CET 2021
```

Comment: I made a date-seq repository that improves on this idea and documents it a bit better. https://github.com/bas080/date-seq

Answer (score 3):

If one wants to loop from input date to any range below can be used, also it will print output in format of yyyyMMdd...

```
#!/bin/bash
in=2018-01-15
while [ "$in" != 2018-01-25 ]; do
  in=$(date -I -d "$in + 1 day")
  x=$(date -d "$in" +%Y%m%d)
  echo $x
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This might also help. Based on [Gilli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54638353/5113030) answer, but a different solution of the issue with an integer conversion.

Basically, while verifying the input, `LoopEachDay` stores the "end" date in **seconds** and compares with it firstly converting the current day into seconds(`date -d "$dateIteration" '+%s'`), too.

```sh
#/bin/bash

RegexVerify()
{
    regex="$1";
    shift;

    if [[ "$@" =~ $regex ]];
    then
        return 0;
    fi

    return 1;
}

VerifyDateISO8601()
{
    if RegexVerify '^[0-9]{4}-(0?[1-9]|10|11|12)-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$' "$1";
    then
        return 0;
    fi

    return 1;
}

# Iterate each day
#
# * The *first* argument is an ISO8601 start date.
# * The *second* argument is an ISO8601 end date or an empty string which assumes
# the current date.
LoopEachDay()
{
    if ! VerifyDateISO8601 "$1";
    then
        return 1;
    fi

    if ! VerifyDateISO8601 "$2" && [ "$2" != '' ];
    then
        return 2;
    fi

    dateIteration="$(date -d "$1" '+%Y-%m-%d')";
    dateIterationEndSeconds="$(date -d "$2" '+%s')";

    while (("$(date -d "$dateIteration" '+%s')" <= dateIterationEndSeconds))
    do
        printf $'%s\n' "$dateIteration"; # A work with "$dateIteration"

        dateIteration="$(date -d "$dateIteration + 1 day" '+%Y-%m-%d')";
    done
}

LoopEachDay '2021-13-01' '';
printf $'Exit code: %s\n\n' "$?";

# Exit code: 1

LoopEachDay '2021-04-01' '';

# 2021-04-01
# 2021-04-02
# 2021-04-03
# 2021-04-04
# 2021-04-05
# 2021-04-06
# 2021-04-07
# 2021-04-08

printf $'\n';
LoopEachDay '2021-04-03' '2021-04-06';

# 2021-04-03
# 2021-04-04
# 2021-04-05
# 2021-04-06
```

Answer (score 1):

For people using macos:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

startdate=2010-01-12
enddate=2010-02-23

sDateTs=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" $startdate "+%s")
eDateTs=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" $enddate "+%s")
dateTs=$sDateTs
offset=86400

while [ "$dateTs" -le "$eDateTs" ]
do
  date=`date -j -f "%s" $dateTs "+%Y-%m-%d"`

  echo $date    # <<--- What you want to do 

  dateTs=$(($dateTs+$offset))
done
```