# BASH looping though time

Tags: bash, date, for-loop, time, increment

Using BASH I want to loop from a start to end date at ten-minute intervals.
I tried

```
begin_date="2015-01-01 00:00:00"
end_date="2015-02-20 00:00:00"
d=$begin_date
while [ "$d" != "$end_date" ]; do
    echo $d
    d=$(date -d "${d} + 10 min" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
done
```

But it didn't work.  Looking at [Bash:Looping thru dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226229/bash-looping-through-dates)

```
#This works
d=$(date -I -d "${d} + 1 day")

#This doesn't work
d=$(date -d "${d} + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

What am I missing in the format string?

Comment: define "it didn't work". What output does it produce?

Comment: It didn't add ten minutes or day.

Comment: The question you link to specifically explains why `-I` is important, but you took it out anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you linked to just needs to be adjusted slightly:

```
#!/bin/bash

## User-specified dates.
# See [GNU Coreutils: Date] for more info
# [GNU Coreutils: Date]: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Combined-date-and-time-of-day-items.html#Combined-date-and-time-of-day-items
begin_date="2015-01-01T00:00"
end_date="2015-01-01T00:40"

# Run through `date` to ensure iso-8601 consistency
startdate=$(date --iso-8601='minutes' --date="${begin_date}")
enddate=$(date --iso-8601='minutes' --date="${end_date}")

# Do loop
d="$startdate"
while [ "$d" != "$enddate" ]; do 
  echo $d
  d=$(date --iso-8601='minutes' --date="$d + 10 minutes")
done
```

Note that the options `-I` and `-d` are equivalent to `--iso-8601` and `--date` respectively.

Comment: Thanks, Sigve, your answer also works.  Not certain if I can tick multiple answers as correct.

Comment: On further testing, I'm changing to accept Sigve's answer.  I ran both methods for a month.  Sigve's was slightly faster (although not by much) 

@tripleee's real    1m1.310s user    0m1.156s sys     0m55.953s vs 
Sigve's     real    0m57.308suser    0m0.953s sys     0m52.250s

However, the reason I changed the answer was that I'm needing four variables derived from the date (old/new path (YYYYMMDD) and old/new name foo_HHMM) and the code above was easy to reformat the date whereas the other code was not.

Comment: Minor correction to start and end dates.  Don't use Z (i.e. UTC).
 `code` 
    begin_date="2015-01-01T00:00"
    end_date="2015-01-01T00:40"
 `code`

Answer (score 2):

The expression `date -d "${d} + 10 min"` seems not to produce a date with an offset of 10 minutes.  In fact, when I run your code, I see a date counter going *backwards.* (Posting this diagnostic as part of your question would help others see where the problem is; you should not require others to run your code just to see what it does.)

Anyway, the sane way to do this is to convert the dates to [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), then take it from there.

```
for ((d=$(date -d "$begin_date" +%s); d <= $(date -d "$end_date" +%s); d += 600))
do
    date -d @$d +"%F %H:%M"
done
```

Doing date arithmetic in the shell is probably going to be rather inefficient; converting this to e.g. Awk or Perl might be worth your time if you find it's too sluggish, or need to run it lots of times.

Comment: Thanks, code works perfectly.  Been battling with that for about 8 hours!  I had to google epoch time to understand your answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; added a Wikipedia link.

Comment: I also experienced this rare _feature_ of time going backwards when saying `+10 min`.

Comment: I think the reason that `+10 min` appears to have time go backwards is that the `+10` part is parsed as a timezone specification if `T00:00` or similar is present in the timestamp. `date -d '2015-01-01T00:00 + 10 + 20 minutes'` gives me `Wed Dec 31 15:20:00 CET 2014`, so an apparent 9 hours back in time because CET is +1 and I asked for +10, and then 20 minutes forward as specified.