# DBT: I need to load historic data in DBT into my type 2 SCD dims. I have parameterized the query. How can I load the history without manually doing so

Tags: dbt

I need to load historic data in DBT into my type 2 SCD dims. I have parameterized the query. How can I load the history without manually changing the parameter in dbt for each day. I need to load 5 years of historic data.

Example; I can run the parameter dbt run --vars '{"run_date": "1/30/2022"}' to run the data for one day. Is there a way where I can create a loop to cycle thru the run dates and load one day at a time of the history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model can absolutely only operate on one date at a time:

1. You could create a custom dbt materialization to do the backfill for you. See the [insert by period materialization](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/materializations/insert_by_period_materialization.sql) for inspiration (note, this macro itself will not do exactly what you want). This has the benefit of being easier to re-run if you ever need to rebuild this table (which you probably will, someday)
2. It would probably be easier to write a shell script to just run dbt many times. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28226339/10813082) on how to do that

But really the best option for you is going to be to re-work your model logic so you can pass in a range of dates (or a list of dates) to your model. This is probably going to be hard, but otherwise building this model in multiple environments is going to be a huge pain.

As an aside, it seems like what you're building is a [snapshot](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/snapshots), not a model. Running models should be idempotent, and models should be built into all dev environments; snapshots not so much.