# Inconsistent results when comparing numeric variables in bash if statement

Tags: bash, shell, date, for-loop, if-statement

I have a `bash` script that performs commands on files based on dates contained in the file names. I'd like certain commands to run only for months greater than the current month, so I attempted to add an `if` statement that compares the variables `$day` (containing the numeric value of the month, taken from the `for` loop's parameter) and `$thismonth` (populated using `date`).

For most values of `month` the script works as expected, but when it loops through `08` and `09` it produces errors, e.g. `value too great for base (error token is "08")`. Is there some difference between the values `08` and `09` and all the others...? Or what other mistake have I made?

Minimal example `test.sh`:

<sup>Note: I'm a scripting novice so please feel free to correct any mistakes or inefficiencies even if not causing this particular issue. Also, parameters of the `for` loop came from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28226303/14974911) to [How to loop through dates using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226229/how-to-loop-through-dates-using-bash).</sup>

```bash
for d in 02{01..28} {04,06,09,11}{01..30} {01,03,05,07,08,10,12}{01..31}
do
    day=${d: -2}
    month=${d::2}
    thismonth=$(date +%m)

    if [[ "$month" -gt "$thismonth" ]]; then
        echo day is $day
        echo the month is $month
        echo this month is $thismonth
        echo Greater than this month
        echo "" # to make output more easily readable
    else
        echo day is $day
        echo the month is $month
        echo this month is $thismonth
        echo NOT greater than this month
        echo "" # to make output more easily readable
    fi
done
```

Expected results:

```
# for values of `month` between `02` and `12`
day is <value of $day>
the month is <value between 02 and 12>
this month is 01
Greater than this month

# when `month` is `01`:
day is <value of $day>
the month is 01
this month is 01
NOT greater than this month
```

Actual results are as expected for all values of `month` ***except*** `08` and `09`. Excerpted output (repetitive lines removed):

```
day is 01
the month is 02
this month is 01
Greater than this month

[ . . . ]

day is 30
the month is 06
this month is 01
Greater than this month

./test.sh: line 7: [[: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
day is 01
the month is 09
this month is 01
NOT greater than this month

[ . . . ]

./test.sh: line 7: [[: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
day is 30
the month is 09
this month is 01
NOT greater than this month

day is 01
the month is 11
this month is 01
Greater than this month

[ . . . ]

day is 30
the month is 11
this month is 01
Greater than this month

day is 01
the month is 01
this month is 01
NOT greater than this month

[ . . . ]

day is 31
the month is 01
this month is 01
NOT greater than this month

day is 01
the month is 03
this month is 01
Greater than this month

[ . . . ]

day is 31
the month is 07
this month is 01
Greater than this month

./test.sh: line 7: [[: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
day is 01
the month is 08
this month is 01
NOT greater than this month

[ . . . ]

./test.sh: line 7: [[: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
day is 31
the month is 08
this month is 01
NOT greater than this month

day is 01
the month is 10
this month is 01
Greater than this month

[ . . . ]

day is 31
the month is 12
this month is 01
Greater than this month
```

This seemed especially surprising since these months are in different groups of the `for` loop parameter (i.e. apparently unrelated to the fact that one loops through days `01` to `30` vs `01` to `31` so also not somehow related to number of days in `thismonth` or something like that).

The full script (which checks for files named with dates formatted `yyyymmdd` and removes certain those with certain dates) worked fine in the latter part of last year when I wanted to see results for all dates, but gave the above odd results when I added the `if` statement in the minimal example in order to prevent output results for months greater than the current one (since no files yet exist for dates later than today).

`bash --version` is `GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release` on `Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)` (actually running Proxmox kernel where `uname -srv` is `Linux 5.15.39-4-pve #1 SMP PVE 5.15.39-4 (Mon, 08 Aug 2022 15:11:15 +0200)` in case that's somehow relevant).

Comment: bash treats numbers that start with "0" as octal.

Comment: Aha, thanks. Missed the dupe questions somehow, but from those discovered that using `if [...]` with single brackets rather than double brackets fixed it.